# Search input with common search values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to create a search input that, when I focus on it, a menu of options shows, and when I select, it can be concatenated to the search text.
Example:

```
  |------------------------------------------------------|
  |  |                                                   |
  |  |                                                   |
  |------------------------------------------------------|

  |                                |
  |  VALUE1                        |
  |--------------------------------|
  |                                |
  |  VALUE2                        |
  |--------------------------------|
```

And when I click on VALUE1 my search text will be like "VALUE1:TEXT_TO_FIND".

This way, I can filter my return data easily from client side.

Thanks,

LN

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Tried but don't know how to do the list option appear.

Comment: Since you tagged [tag:jquery], look for jQuery UI's Autocomplete. You just need to provide it a list of values to display.

Comment: What I need is to instantly give a list of options to select when i focus on the search input. These are all autocomplete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Chosen jQuery Plugin](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) might be a good option.

Comment: What I need is to instantly give a list of options to select when i focus on the search input. This is only autocomplete, a nice one but not what i'm looking for. Sorry if misunderstood.

Comment: I updated from the twitter typeahead to the chosen jquery plugin.

Answer (score 1):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4tj6r/58/)

```
<input type="text" id="field" /><br>
<select style="display:none;" id="hint" size="4">
</select>

...

var words = ["base","barrel","barbie","battle","bell","bench","breach"];
function init(){
    document.getElementById('field').onkeyup = hint;
    document.getElementById('hint').onchange = select;
}
function hint(){
    var hintElement = document.getElementById('hint');
    var fieldElement = document.getElementById('field');
    var str = fieldElement.value.substring(fieldElement.value.lastIndexOf(' ')+1);
    if(str == '')
        return;
    hintElement.innerHTML = '';
    for(var i in words)
        if(words[i].substring(0,str.length) == str)
            hintElement.innerHTML += '<option value="'+words[i]+'">'+words[i]+'</option>';
        hintElement.style.display = (hintElement.innerHTML == '') ? 'none' : '';
}
function select(){
    var fieldElement = document.getElementById('field');
    fieldElement.value = fieldElement.value.substring(0,fieldElement.value.lastIndexOf(' ')+1) +  this.value + ' ';
    this.innerHTML = '';
    this.style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('field').focus();
}
init();
```